# Entity Framework defaultconnectionfactory

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I've recently created a new web project using entity framework 4.3. I'm using database first design.

Entity Framework added this section to my web.config, which is giving some informational error messages. I've read somewhere that this code relates to code first design - do I need it - do I just remove it?

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @JoeR I don't think there is one.

Comment: I don't understand "giving some informational error messages" then...

Comment: @JoeR I may have misinterpreted it but I assume it's related to the XML warnings/hints you get sometimes. Have you tried removing the configuration and seeing if your app runs ok? That looks like your using SQLCE 4.0, if so I would imagine you would need it.

Comment: @JoeR - this is one of the messages: Could not find schema information for the element 'defaultConnectionFactory'. I get similar messages for entityFramework, Parameter, Parameters and Type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if it matters if you aren't using CodeFirst (try removing it and see if it runs ok). However, if you are using CodeFirst and using SQLCE 4.0 as your main database then you need to keep it. See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx):

> If you don’t set a default connection factory, Code First uses the SqlConnectionFactory, pointing to .\SQLEXPRESS. SqlConnectionFactory also has a constructor that allows you to override parts of the connection string. If you want to use a SQL Server instance other than .\SQLEXPRESS you can use this constructor to set the server.

Answer (score 24):

This may be very relevant (emphasis mine):

> The configuration section allows you to specify a default connection factory that Code First should use to locate a database to use for a context. **The default connection factory is only used when no connection string has been added to the configuration file for a context**.

See [Entity Framework Config File Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You get those warning messages because the section element definition for entityFramework is missing in `Web.config`. It looks something like this: (note: the below is for EF5.0)

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```